# Wyse DHCP Option Tag

Tags: dhcp, windows-server-2012, thin-client

I have a new Wyse R10L that I am testing, and I have found a tutorial video for configuring it on my network (a test Server 2012 environment).

The instructions say to "set a DHCP option tag 161" to a certain value. When I go into my DHCP options though, 161 is not an option in the list.

Can anyone please tell me how I get that in there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a "Predefined Option". The UI is mostly the same as it was in Windows Server 2008 R2.

From the DHCP management console, right-click the the "IPv4" node, choose "Set Predefined Options...", and click "Add" to add the new option definition.

If you'd prefer to do it from PowerShell have a look at the [Add-DhcpServerv4OptionDefinition](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj590734.aspx) cmdlet.

For this option I believe you're looking at a "String" type. Your documentation from Wyse should say for sure.